# How to limit the number of guesses in Hangman in Java

Tags: java, exception, counter

So i have my code working great.  I just need help in limiting the number of guesses.  And every time you make a wrong guess, to have a counter to tell you how many guesses you have left.

So I want to set the limit of guesses to 15.  So every time you make an incorrect a bad guess counter displays to the user to (increase pressure/stress) 14 guesses left, or you lose.

Here's my code:

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {
    private final static int maxGuesses = 5;


    static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        static boolean isCorrect;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // getting file
            File filename = new File("hangman.txt");
            if (!filename.exists()) {
                System.out.println(filename.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println(filename + " does not exist.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            // reading word file
            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(filename);
                while (input.hasNext()) {
                    words.add(input.next());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // debug: display words
            //System.out.println(words);

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String playStats = "y";
            while (playStats.equals("y")) {
                String word = getWord();
                String hiddenWord = getHiddenWord(word);
                int missCount = 0;


                    while (true) {
                    System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + hiddenWord + " > ");
                    char ch = input.next().charAt(0);

                    if (!isAlreadyInWord(hiddenWord, ch)) {

                        hiddenWord = getGuess(word, hiddenWord, ch);
                        if (missCount>maxGuesses){
                           // Print info on max guesses reached
                         System.out.println("you have reached" + missCount + "you have" + maxGuesses + 
                                 " left");
                           break;
                          }
                        if(word.equals(hiddenWord)) {

                        if (!isCorrect) {
                            System.out.println(ch + " is not in the word.");
                            missCount++;
                        }   
                    else {
                        System.out.println(ch + " is already in word.");
                    }
                        break;
                        } 
                        }
                    }
                System.out.println("The word is " + hiddenWord + " You missed " + missCount + " times");
                System.out.println("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n >");
                playStats = input.next();
            }

        }

        public static String getWord() {
            return words.get((int) (Math.random() * words.size()));
        }

        public static String getHiddenWord(String word) {

            String hidden = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                hidden += "*";
            }
            return hidden;
        }

        static public String getGuess(String word, String hiddenWord, char ch) {

            isCorrect = false;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(hiddenWord);
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

                if (ch == word.charAt(i) && s.charAt(i) == '*') {
                    isCorrect = true;
                    s = s.deleteCharAt(i);
                    s = s.insert(i, ch);
                }
            }
            return s.toString();
        }

        public static boolean isAlreadyInWord(String hiddenWord, char ch) {

            for (int i = 0; i < hiddenWord.length(); i++) {

                if (ch == hiddenWord.charAt(i)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with my "missCount" as the counter.... but how can i write in there that the missCount cannot exceed 15 tries and to display the number of tries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Joe C downvote all you want.  You didn't read my question.  There is no problem. I specifically prefaced that my code was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that my suggestion is not an elegant solution.

- Create a static final maxGuesses with a value (e.g. 15).
- Change the while-condition from `!word.equals(hiddenWord)` to `true`. This loop would now never terminate - unless we introduce `break`statements.
- Create a new check (if-condition) to see if the number of tries was exceeded (e.g. `missCount>maxGuesses`). Print this information in the if-block and also add the `break` to exit the inner while.
- Create another check (if-condition) with `word.equals(hiddenWord)` in -  this is used to figure out if the word was found. Print the information about the found word as part of the if-block and also add the `break` statement
- Both checks should be part of the inner while-loop.

.

```
while (true) { 
  if (missedCount>maxGuesses){
   // Print info on max guesses reached
   break;
  }
  // Does the read input stuff
  if (word.equals(hiddenWord)){
   // Print info on word was guessed
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: So i updated my code, you can see above.  Now all it does it keeps repeating "Enter a Letter in word *****>" until you get the word right no matter how many tries, how was i supposed to include the new code, did i do it right?

Comment: also, as you can see i just put the limit to 5 just to see how quickly the code would stop it

Comment: Please review your code  starting at `if(word.equals(hiddenWord)) {` To me the logic seems to be not ok: The missCount is only incremented when you already have found the word.